# access custom attribute using serializeArray()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using `serializeArray()` function to fetch `name` and `value` attrubute of input tags resides in the `form` tag.

```
<form>
   <input type='text' data-val="Employee Name" value='john' name ='empName'/>
   <input type='text' data-val="Employee id" value='4333' name ='empId'/>
</form>
```

i am able to access `name` and `value` attributes , but how can i access custom attribute `data-val` using `serializeArray()`

Answer (score 7):

In this case you can't use serializeArray, you can try something like this with the help of `map()`

```js
var arr=$('input').map(function(){ return $(this).data('val');}).get();
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
   <input type='text' data-val="Employee Name" value='john' name ='empName'/>
   <input type='text' data-val="Employee id" value='4333' name ='empId'/>
</form>
```

If you want the result as name value pair then use

```js
var arr = $('input').map(function() {
  return {
    [$(this).attr('name')] : $(this).data('val')
  }
}).get();
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type='text' data-val="Employee Name" value='john' name='empName' />
  <input type='text' data-val="Employee id" value='4333' name='empId' />
</form>
```

Same output as `serializeArray`

```js
var arr = $('input').map(function() {
  return {
    name: $(this).attr('name'),
    value: $(this).data('val')
  }
}).get();
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type='text' data-val="Employee Name" value='john' name='empName' />
  <input type='text' data-val="Employee id" value='4333' name='empId' />
</form>
```

Comment: your name value pair solution has syntactical error

Comment: @rafe need to wrap prop with `[  ]`